# Oauth 1.0 in Mulesoft - Using Anytime Studio in Eclipse

Tags: mule, netsuite, mule-studio, oauth-1.0a

All - I am trying to configure an HTTP connector to use Oauth1.0 instead of Basic Authentication with the Anytime Studio IDE for Eclipse. I am used to configuring the connection in the drag/drop interface of middleware, but never touching the source code. For this project, we edit the Java code to configure the connection, so I assume I will need to load some other Java class to get the Nonce and Timestamp. Does anyone have any experience/examples of implementing Oauth 1.0 in Mulesoft? in their documentation, I only see references to Oauth 2.0 and HTTP connections, not 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent documentation can be found here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connector-devkit/3.9/oauth-v1

Comment: I saw this page, but do you have a code example of the configuration for Oauth 1.0 and an HTTPS connection? very new to AnytimeStudio IDE interface in Eclipse